# Show an image and a message in a toast notification on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to show an Image and text on windows phone. The text works but the image does not show up at all the docs on msdn says that it should though

here is my code ...

```
        ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02;
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

        XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Hello World!"));
        XmlNodeList toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///assets/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png");
        ((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "red graphic");
        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

**Results**

[image]

**Expected Results**

[image]

Image Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot include an image in a toast on Windows Phone 8.1. The template will always be the app's logo then two text fields.

This is documented near the top of the [Toast Template Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761494.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

Comment: The quick start does not spell this out very well, thank you for your answer ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868254.aspx.

Comment: The quickstart has the same text where it talks about picking the template in step 2. That said, if you find the documentation confusing you can leave feedback at the bottom of the page where it says "was this page helpful?" After you mark yes or know you'll be able to provide more detailed feedback